# TypeError member is undefined

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Hello I create this Typescript class to reuse my search.

```
    export class WorkerSearch {

        private loadingWorkers: Ref<boolean>;
        private possibleWorkers: Ref<UnwrapRef<Array<TsadWorker>>>;

        constructor(loadingWorkers: Ref<boolean>, possibleWorkers: Ref<UnwrapRef<TsadWorker[]>>) {
            this.loadingWorkers = loadingWorkers;
            this.possibleWorkers = possibleWorkers;
        }

        public workerSearch(email: string) {
            console.log("worker search");
            this.loadingWorkers.value = true;
            const map = new Map<string, StringFilterField>();
            map.set("email", StringFilterField.fromValue(email));
            const searchRequest = new SearchRequest(10, 0, map);
            axios
                .post(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + "users/workers/search", searchRequest)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("response recieved")
                    this.possibleWorkers.value = response.data
                    this.loadingWorkers.value = false
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    defaultErrorHandler(error)
                })
        }
    }
```

But when using it there is a error at the console: "error TypeError: this.loadingWorkers is undefined"
If i remove ' this.loadingWorkers = true' the error says "error TypeError: this.possibleWorkers is undefined".

How is this even possible?

This is the constructor call:

```
    let loadingWorkers = ref(false);
    let possibleWorkers = ref(new Array<TsadWorker>());
    const workerSearchObj = new WorkerSearch(loadingWorkers, possibleWorkers);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: is there a possibility `ref( )` returns `undefined`?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I checked with console.log and it retuns a object

Comment: If loadingWorkers and possibleWorkers are possibly `undefined` when `workerSearch` is called, then you can't read or write their `value` property without checking if the ref exists first.

Comment: Sorry but it seams like loadinWorkers and possibleWorkers can't be undefinded. I tried to check 'loadinWorkers == undefined' but the compiler complains need to use loadingWorkers.value.

Comment: Have you logged the two properties from inside `workerSearch` as well as the axios callback?

Comment: Yes, in workerSearch and axios the are undefined. But when passed to the constuctor the are valid objects.

Comment: Are you calling it as `workerSearchObj.workerSearch()` or are you assigning `workerSearchObj.workerSearch` as a function to some other variable/passing it as an argument?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239804/discussion-between-ace-of-spade-and-dustincompetent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `workerSearch` method is unbound when you extract it from your `WorkerSearch` instance and pass it somewhere else, that is, `this` is not necessarily `workerSearchObj` when not calling the method as `workerSearchObj.workerSearch()`

```
let loadingWorkers = ref(false);
let possibleWorkers = ref(new Array<TsadWorker>());
const workerSearchObj = new WorkerSearch(loadingWorkers, possibleWorkers);

// instead of
doSomethingWith(workerSearchObj.workerSearch)
// bind the value of `this` before passing the function
doSomethingWith(workerSearchObj.workerSearch.bind(workerSearchObj))
// or wrap the function
doSomethingWith(mail => workerSearchObj.workerSearch(mail))

// or bind the function from within the class constructor
export class WorkerSearch {
    // ...
    constructor(loadingWorkers: Ref<boolean>, possibleWorkers: Ref<UnwrapRef<TsadWorker[]>>) {
        // ...
        this.workerSearch = this.workerSearch.bind(this);
    }
    // ...
}
```